# Performance penalty if going through Java base class?

Tags: java, performance

I want to use a `Collection` whose type is known at compile time (`ArrayList`). Is there any penalty going through the parent class interface?

```
Collection<Integer> v = new ArrayList<>();
v.add(42);
```

versus

```
ArrayList<Integer> v = new ArrayList<>();
v.add(42);
```

In C++, the first case would result in a virtual function call, but not the second one. Is it the same in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses dynamic binding for all method calls, so there is no difference (they're equally bad if you will, with the caveat that JIT optimizations will probably make them equally good).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no penalty.  Your ArrayList is exactly the same object, with exactly the same type.  In fact, referring to it as a Collection is a good object-oriented practice, since you are referring to the object by its contract rather than its implementation.